# C# .Net receiving UDp packets in separater thread and application exit

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, udp

In my Winforms application, I am receiving data over UDP in a dedicated thread and raising an event every time a new data packet has been received. The application works fine, but the problem is that in the application exit, the UDP listener keeps listening and thus keeps the app running.

Threading is not very familiar topic to me, so my question is what is the correct way to close the UDP listening thread? Also, I would like to understand why doesnt the UDP listener exit the while loop when I call the StopListener() from the main thread.

My UDP listener looks like this:

```
class UDPListener
{
    private int m_portToListen = 2003;
    private volatile bool listening;
    Thread m_ListeningThread;
    public event EventHandler<MyMessageArgs> NewMessageReceived;                       

    //constructor
    public UDPListener()
    {
        this.listening = false;
    }

    public void StartListener(int exceptedMessageLength)
    {
        if (!this.listening)
        {
            m_ListeningThread = new Thread(ListenForUDPPackages);
            this.listening = true;
            m_ListeningThread.Start();
        }
    }

    public void StopListener()
    {
        this.listening = false;            
    }

    public void ListenForUDPPackages()
    {
        UdpClient listener = null;
        try
        {
            listener = new UdpClient(m_portToListen);
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            //do nothing
        }

        if (listener != null)
        {
            IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, m_portToListen);

            try
            {
                while (this.listening)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for UDP broadcast to port " +m_portToListen);
                    byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);       

                    //raise event                        
                    NewMessageReceived(this, new MyMessageArgs(bytes)); 
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                listener.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Done listening for UDP broadcast");
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MyMessageArgs : EventArgs
{
    public byte[] data { get; set; }

    public MyMessageArgs(byte[] newData)
    {
        data = newData;            
    }
}
```

And in the MainWindow_FormClosing() event (in the main UI thread) I do the following:

```
  m_udpListener.StopListener();
  this.m_udpListener.NewMessageReceived -= OnNewMessageReceived;
```

The way the app works now is after application exit, the application is left hanging, but the next received UDP packet raises an exception in the UDP listener, and then the finally block gets executed, but not before.

Clearly I have misunderstood something, help would be appreciated!

Comment: im not real familiar with it myself - although im trying, it looks to me like you are just resetting the listening flag, rather then stopping the listener. exiting the while loop will stop it from reading the buffer but leaves the thread running, if im reading it right. You might need to set 
Thread.IsBackground = True

When the main thread closes it will automatically kill all background threads; it won't kill foreground threads.

The other option is to keep a global variable for the thread and abort it from the FormClosing or Dispose method of the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks OK but you can add a few lines to make Closing more reliable.

```
public void StopListener()
{
    this.listening = false;            
    listener .Close();   // forcibly end communication 
}
```

Stopping requires a little time, so call this as early as possible (ie from the Close button and not from Window_Closed event) :

```
  // first disconnect the event
  this.m_udpListener.NewMessageReceived -= OnNewMessageReceived;
  m_udpListener.StopListener(); 
  Application.DoEvents();          // allow processing of outstanding packets
```

And although it should not critical, I would make the Thread a background one:

```
     m_ListeningThread = new Thread(ListenForUDPPackages);
     m_ListeningThread.IsBackground = true;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am marking this as the answer, because just setting the IsBackground to true solves my whole problem - the UDP listener thread is killed at the application exit. 

But I still dont get why setting the listening to false does not exit the while loop. Could it because the listening variable is volatile? 

And also, if i don not do the listener.Close() before the app exits (and the thread is killed), are there some resources left hanging? In other words, do I even have to bother closing the listener if it is working in a background thread?

Comment: Yeah the strange thing is that while loop does not break on a breakpoint unless there is a udp message coming through. Doesn't make sense to me either. Setting the thread to background fixed it for me too.

Answer (score 4):

I know this thread is a bit old but I stumbled across it looking for UDP info.

Anyway the reason setting listening to false does not exit the while loop?

```
byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
```

is a blocking  the thread waiting for a receive byte.  See [UdpClient.Receive Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

`while (this.listening)`

will only get checked after a byte is received. By then it is to late.

Answer (score 0):

i was there one time, your code is OK, just a thread misunderstanding how open and close a thread safe, just read this :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart(v=vs.110).aspx

edit this line in your code :

```
m_ListeningThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForUDPPackages));
```