# EventHandler missing, don't know how to initialize

Tags: c#, multithreading, udp, eventhandler

I just wanted to use the code from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572854/c-sharp-net-receiving-udp-packets-in-separater-thread-and-application-exit) (first post) to test something, I'm not really familiar with C#, but it crashed when a package is sent to the server at the following line:

`NewMessageReceived(this, new MyMessageArgs(bytes));`

with the following error message:

`System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

I think because NewMessageReceived is not initialized, but how do i do? Can anybody help me out? I can't find useful tips for EventHandlers in C#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If no one has subscribed to `NewMessageReceived`, the handler will be `null`. Thus, you need to null check `NewMessageReceived` before invoking. For thread-safety, preventing situations where the handler may become null after the check and before the invoke, store the event handler in a local first: `var tempEvent = NewMessageReceived; if(tempEvent != null) tempEvent(this, new MyMessageArgs(bytes));`

Comment: Debug to see if bytes contains a null reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An event must have at least 1 subscriber for you to raise it. Put a null check first before calling.

```
if (NewMessageReceived != null)
{
    NewMessageReceived(this, new MyMessageArgs(bytes));
}
```